# Facebook login without redirection

Tags: facebook, redirect, authentication

Our website runs in public computers and the browser is restricted to our own site. Facebook needs a redirection for security reasons. Can this be avoided somehow?
If not, which are the urls I'd have to allow/unlock?

Comment: Have you checked the docs on the developer page of Facebook. The URLs should be accessible there.

Comment: I didn't find any list. I even unlocked all facebook urls.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2#login

You need to use the following structure:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={app-id}&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
```

Have a look at the hints in the blue box at the bottom of the docs paragraph:

> When using a desktop app and logging in, Facebook redirects people to the redirect_uri mentioned above and places an access token along with some other metadata (such as token expiry time) in the URI fragment:
>
> https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN...
>
> Your app needs to detect this redirect and then read the access token out of the URI using the mechanisms provided by the OS and development framework you are using. You can then skip straight to the Inspecting access tokens step.

Comment: You keep pasting the same thing. Can you explain what `Your app needs to detect this redirect and then read the access token out of the URI using the mechanisms provided by the OS and development framework you are using. ` means?